# Puppet Testing if a file exist

Tags: puppet

Im looking for a way to test if a file exist in my client (just test not creation).
I've found the way (File.exists) in chef but that wasn't simple with puppet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "native" way to do this without execs if you're on Puppet 2.6.6+:

```
file { '/path/to/myfile':
  ensure => 'present',
  audit  => 'all',
}
```

(This functionality exists since Puppet 2.6.0, but there were a number of issues with auditing that only really got hammered out with the 2.6.6 release.)

If you're on an older version, you can also tell the resource to run in `noop` mode, which will just display a message when Puppet is run and the file doesn't exist:

```
file { '/path/to/myfile':
  ensure => 'present',
  noop   => 'true',
}
```

Comment: yeah. this is great with new version ov puppet. ive been working with pre 2.6.0 and have to write my own ruby function for file exist/empty check.

Answer (score 9):

You should create yours own function or use exec with onlyif command.
something like :

```
exec { "mycommand":
  path => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin",
  onlyif => "test -f /etc/blalba" //yours command 
}
```

Comment: ensure => present will create the file if its not existing. bazic only wants to test and not create it.
See docs: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/type.html#file

Comment: Thanks,but nothing interesting in docs.

Comment: ive updated my my answer

Comment: @MealstroM: Wouldn't "`creates => '/etc/blabla'`" be better than an "`onlyif`"?

Comment: @freiheit `creates =>... ` is something different. it means that `exec command` should create file in `creates => ` and if there is no this file than the command runs. and if you just want to check some /run/pid this command isnt good. and with `onlyif` you can check empty or not the file is  :D

Comment: @MealstroM: In this particular case, `creates` would have the same result and be much simpler (and a bit faster). Yes, in general `onlyif` does provide more flexibility.